# How do I get edit text to save multiple times?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this layout with a button that when clicked takes the user to a page with two edit texts, one for a question and one for an answer. When the check button on that activity is clicked, the user is taken back to the previous activity with a new dynamic button created with the text set to the question. I've got the inputted edit text to save. My problem is that when I try to edit an already existing edit text, it does not save and instead stays to the originally inputted texts. I know the problem is that in my code, I have it so that the intent is accessed only when the plus button on the first page is clicked, however, I have no idea how to get the edit text to save again when the button on the edit text page is clicked.

Main page:

```
    package com.example.uh

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val questionActivityCode = 2
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener{
            startActivityForResult(Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java), questionActivityCode)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == questionActivityCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            createNewButtonWithText(data?.getStringExtra("test") ?: "", data?.getStringExtra("test2") ?: "")
        }
    }

    private fun createNewButtonWithText(text: String, s: String)
    {
        val newbutton = Button(this@MainActivity)
        val layout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainlayout)
        newbutton.text = text
        newbutton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        newbutton.width=1010
        newbutton.height=300
        newbutton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        newbutton.translationX= 65F
        newbutton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"))
        newbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#250A43"))
        layout.addView(newbutton)

        val inflator = layoutInflater
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val intent1 = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)
        intent1.putExtra("test", text)
        intent1.putExtra("test2", s)

        newbutton.setOnClickListener{
            val dialogLayout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.text, null)
            with(builder) {
                setTitle(newbutton.text)
                setPositiveButton("Edit"){dialog, which ->
                    startActivity(intent1)
                }
                setNegativeButton("Delete"){dialog, which ->
                    layout.removeView(newbutton)
                }
                setView(dialogLayout)
                show()
            }
        }
    }}
```

Second page:

```
    package com.example.uh

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val questionActivityCode = 2
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val question = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.question)
        val answer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)

        val value = intent.getStringExtra("test")
        question.setText(value)
        val value2 = intent.getStringExtra("test2")
        answer.setText(value2)


        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.btn3).setOnClickListener {
            val questiontext = question.text.toString()
            val answertext = answer.text.toString()

            val answer2 = intent.putExtra("answer", answertext)

            val returnIntent = Intent()
            returnIntent.putExtra("test", questiontext)
            returnIntent.putExtra("test2", answertext)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)

            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use shared preference to achieve that